# Weird Tempo Translation Between Digital Performer 7.24 and Reason 5

Tags: audio-recording

After researching the problem on line, it appears that Reason doesn't always do well with Digital-Performer-programmed tempo/meter changes when running in ReWire mode. It gets confused and stutters/drops beats.

Is there a known work-around for this issue?

Comment: Perhaps linking some of the online research could help spur someone to a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had tempo problems with Ableton/Reason using Rewire, the solution I found was simple:

Move all tempo automation from Ableton to Reason.

For some weird reason, it works fine when Reason changes tempo, but not when Live does it. 
Maybe this solution can be use in your case.